# Drop index not working SQlite Android

Tags: android, sqlite, indexing

I tried this two queries on a database which already has indexes defined:

```
myDB.rawQuery("drop index my_index", null);
myDB.rawQuery("create index my_index on mytable(row_table)", null);
```

And I get this error:

```
(1) index my_index already exists
```

And yet, when I do these very sames queries into a shell on my computer with sqlite3, it works perfectly!

What is wrong with these queries on Android?

Comment: Do you have a transaction started when you do that?

Comment: No transaction is started.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `IF EXISTS` clause to attempt to drop index only if it exists, thus avoiding an error about missing index:

```
database.execSQL("DROP INDEX IF EXISTS INDEX_NAME")
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience sqlite(3) does not allow you to DROP an index. It seems you have to DROP the table and that in turn DROPS the index.

Answer (score 0):

Use `execSQL()` and not `rawQuery()` for database schema operations.

`execSQL()` both compiles and runs the SQL program.

`rawQuery()` only compiles the SQL program but defers its execution to moving on the returned `Cursor`. Compiling the SQL does validate identifiers such as table/column/index names so that's why you get the error with `rawQuery()`.

Comment: (Yes, an old question that was bumped up by another answer.)